# Having starter issue

Tags: electrical

My starter motor is good, I can jump the solenoid and start my truck. Why isn't it working from the switch which was working before I put a new starter motor on?

Comment: Did you change the starter solenoid as well?

Comment: Yes, I did change the solenoid also . there's no power coming from the small wire to the solenoid.

Comment: Wondering two things: Why are you using two different screen names if @Wm632000 and William Atwood are the same? Also, what year/make/model/engine of car? What have you done to try and diagnose? Give us some information.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you have either a faulty ignition switch or a break in your excitor cable somewhere (the small wire that goes live when you turn the key).

I had the exact same issue on my Volkswagen Bora and traced it back to the wire, around 3 inches from the point it connects to the starter.  It made a tight bend back on itself and the heat of the engine had caused it to go brittle, loose it's insulation, corrode and snap.  Thankfully it was a very easy fix.

Obviously is the ignition switch is at fault this wire will never be made live so this should also be checked.

It would be helpful to know the make and year of your car incase there are specific peculiarities (such as an engine immobiliser) to consider.